# Trying to change data in Linked List nodes

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I have added data (double values from 1.0 - 9.0) to each of my nodes. Now I am trying to access each data to modify it so that the double values in each node are negative (-1.0 through -9.0):

```
void traverseList(struct List *list, void (*func) (void *)) {
    struct Node *current = list->head;
    while(current) {
        func(current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void changeToNegative(void *data) {
    double newData = *((double*)data) * -1.0;
    data = &newData;
}
```

I am calling the above with:

```
traverseList(&list, &changeToNegative);
traverseList(&list, &print);
```

However, it still prints out only the positive values...I am reassigning a new memory location to data, so I don't understand how it is still pointing to the old memory location.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is the declaration for `Node`?

Comment: struct Node {
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
};

Comment: Please give an example of how you create and use your `List`. The solutions selected below are on the right track but are incomplete because your question is missing important details for us to provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void changeToNegative(void *data) {
    double newData = *((double*)data) * -1.0;
    data = &newData;
}
```

The last line of this function sets the *pointer* named `data` to point to a new location than the one originally passed to the function. It does *not* affect the data stored at the original memory location. Instead you want to dereference the pointer and set it to the new value:

```
*data = *((double*)newData);
```

Comment: why is it that when compiling the code with the above changes I receive these errors:                                          warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
mylist.c:110:5: error: invalid use of void expression

Comment: @user1889966 Because my suggested solution is incorrect. In order to fix my answer, I need some more details, though. See my comment to your question.

Comment: I am refraining from posting all my code but thank you for your insight, I have a better understanding of my mistake and how pointers work.

Comment: I believe the problem lies in the fact that newData is of type double. Thus, assigning it to data of type void will cause an error.

Comment: @user1889966 Thank you for being conscious about not posting code that is irrelevant to your question. At the same time, you need to be careful about removing code which is necessary to clarify your question. For some suggestions about finding this balance, check out [this page](http://www.sscce.org). When I ask questions, I often find it helpful to start a new stand-alone program which illustrates the difficulty I have encountered.

Comment: @user1889966 Doing so, I often find my own solution. If I don't, the problem is much more clear in my mind so that I can more easily ask a cogent question here on SO and obtain helpful answers in a more timely manner. I hope these suggestions help you more in the future. And I look forward to more of your questions ;-)

Comment: @user1889966 You are correct that you cannot assign a `double` value to a variable of type `void`, if such a thing even exists. Another issue arises before anything with the assignment operator: you cannot use the `*` dereferencing operator with a `void*` variable. I will edit my answer to show how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I often use the same method when encountering such problems, and I have found a resolution to this question :)

Comment: But I notice your are helping OP greatly in comment ..nice answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code as below. Instead of assigning pointer to data assign value as below

```
void changeToNegative(void *data) {
   double newData = *((double*)data) * -1.0;
   *data = newData;
}
```

This way you will be modifying the value pointed to by data and changes will be persistent.

Comment: +1 for the correct solution. My guess is that the downvote was for the originally answer which only contained code.

Answer (score 2):

**Your error:**

```
void changeToNegative(void *data) {
    double newData = *((double*)data) * -1.0;
    data = &newData;
}
```

In function `changeToNegative(void *data)` you are modifying `data`. While you are to modify `*data`. 
See argument is `void* data` that is pass by address so that reflect change in calling function.

Simply do like:

```
   void changeToNegative(void *data) { 
      *((double*)data) *=-1;   // nagt value pointed data pointer
   }
```

Comment: The original code doesn't "return" anything, even with your loose definition of the word. It changes the value of a local variable (a pointer), but does not change the value of the memory that the pointer orignally pointed to.

Comment: Thank you. Total newbie at C, finding pointers a bit difficult.

Comment: @Code-Guru: well, OK… it completely depends of your idea of why the author comes to do erroneous code: trying to assign a new value to the memory pointed, or trying to assign a new pointer to a new memory with the modified value.

Comment: +1 This is the most correct answer so far because of the cast from `void*` to `double*`. It is difficult to be certain, however, because the OP does not include enough information to be sure that `data` really points to a `double`.

Comment: Regardless of the OP's intent, your explanation of why the code is erroneous is itself incorrect. The original code changes the value of a *local* variable which is not reflected in the original variable passed to the function. It does *not* return a pointer to a local variable by any possible definition of the word "return".

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan As far as I can tell, your edit is correct. Is there a reason you edited this answer rather than posting your own?

Comment: @Code-Guru Ah Code-Guru When I came to this post I saw question was already answered.  qPCR4vir's answer was good but I feel OP will find it helpful if I add some more words. Its fun to work together on good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void changeToNegative(void *data) {
    double* theData = (double*)data;
    *theData = (*theData) * -1.0;
}
```

You were assigning the local copy of `data` within the `changeToNegative` function with the address of the modified data, which will not be reflected in the caller's function. Instead de-reference and modify the `data` in-place so that the change is reflected back to the caller.

Comment: What does it mean to multiply a pointer by -1? Does that even compile?

Comment: Also, the original code does *not* return the address of a local variable. It sets a local pointer variable to point to another local variable, which is perfectly valid but does not do what the OP wants.

Comment: By perfectly valid, you mean compiler does not complain? Returning back from the function, the address of a variable on the stack is not something that you would want to do anytime.

Comment: There is no return statement in the OP's code; it sets a local pointer to point to a local variable which is well defined. The runtime error that you refer to does not apply here.